# Selecting group layer using arcpy.GetParameterAsText()?

Tags: arcpy, group-layer

I have a script that allows me apply a single SQL Definition Query to all feature classes within a particular Group Layer.  For ease of input for others in the office, I changed this into a model tool, and so rather than typing these values into the python script itself, a dialog pops up with two text boxes/drop down menus.

One of the input boxes is just a SQL Expression data type, and the other uses the "Group Layer" data type, so it populates a drop down list of all group layers within the map.  Using this method, the drop down **does** populate with all the map's group layers and I am able to select a group layer.  However, the script doesn't work (though it doesn't throw any errors).  If I instead type the Group Layer name directly into the script with quotes around it, it works properly.  What am I doing wrong?  I'm sure it's something simple, but I'm new to scripting.  Script code as follows:

```
 groupLayer = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
 sql = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
 mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument ("CURRENT")

 for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
     if not lyr.isGroupLayer:
         continue
     if not lyr.name == groupLayer:
         continue
     for subLyr in lyr:
         subLyr.definitionQuery = sql
```

Comment: Play with type of parameter

Comment: Alternatively use groupLayer.name in Lislayers as wildcard. It will also make 1st if redundant

Comment: Add an `arcpy.AddMessage (groupLayer)` before the start of the `for` loop. In ArcMap this will print the variable's value in the progress window. Does the variable contain the name of the group layer?

Comment: @Emil Brundage I tested with the arcpy.AddMessage, and it looks like my problem may have something to do with the fact that we have nested Group Layers.  It my test, it printed "Noxious Weeds\Points" because the Group Layer I tested is the "Points" group layer, which is within the "Noxious Weeds" group layer.  In some  cases we have group layers nested even a couple of layers deeper.  Any suggestions on how to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it appears to be a subgroup layer problem, `if not lyr.name == groupLayer:` should be changed to `if not lyr.longName == groupLayer:`.

```
groupLayer = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
sql = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument ("CURRENT")

for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    if not lyr.isGroupLayer:
        continue
    if not lyr.longName == groupLayer:
        continue
    for subLyr in lyr:
        subLyr.definitionQuery = sql
```

Comment: It works perfectly now.  Thank you very very much!